# Clear just a <textarea> in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have this code which resets the form brilliantly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#formname").resetForm();
</script>
```

but I would like to clear just the text area. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Clear* and *reset* are two different things.  clears means set the value to an empty string while reset means set the value to it's initial value.

**Clear:**

```
$('#textAreaId').val('');// clears the textarea.
```

**Reset** to the textarea initial value instead of just reset it:

```
var t = document.getElementById('textAreaId');
t.value = t.defaultValue;
```

> **defaultValue**  The default value as originally specified in HTML that created this object.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GK8Ca/)

Comment: @Doorknob, not sure what's the problem with `.val('')`, using jquery's id selector is much simpler than `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Kolink, yeah right... check how many times an average browser can perform `$('#id')` 100,000? more? I hope hell is something like that, it might be even better than heaven!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

```
document.getElementById("formname").getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = "";
```

Of course, this can be made simpler if you give the textarea an ID:

```
document.getElementById("textareaID").value = "";
```

Side-note: Here's a better way to reset the form: `document.getElementById('formname').reset();`

Comment: OP is using jQuery. You should have provided a solution in the OPs chosen framework and then advise of any benefits it may have using the equivalent JavaScript only solution. Instead you are simply doing the exact same thing which is mentioned here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question Only in reverse.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, regarding to the first line, I agree, the others are fine, you don't have to use jQuery all the time.

Comment: @gdoron: I totally agree. I made it my personal mission to not use jQuery in my personal pet-projects to learn more about JavaScript and to then appreciate some of the complexity jQuery takes care of for me. The first thing I did when learning JavaScript through jQuery was got to the MDN and see how to do it not using jQuery. But on SO if someone is using a specific library or logic in there question, I try to respect that in my answers and in addition maybe advise of an alternative. We can't just bully everyone into thinking the same as us. I don't think that is the right way to go about.

Comment: BTW, `formname` isn't a good placeholder to a form **id**... :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, I agree  *Doorknob* comments were awful, and I even flagged them.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JGeRe/1)**

Use `.value= ""` when targeting the text area

```
document.getElementById("t").value= "";
```